# Can't implement Google API Sample (VoiceRecognition)

Tags: android, voice-recording

I am very new to Android development, I am trying to create a basic application that makes use of the VoiceRecognition facility to display the text spoken...

```
package com.example.android.apis.app;

import com.example.android.apis.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Sample code that invokes the speech recognition intent API.
 */
public class VoiceRecognition extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private ListView mList;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
        setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);

        // Get display items for later interaction
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
     */
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    matches));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I created a class with the VoiceRecognition code provided by Google:

It took ages to compile as it kept complaining about the "com.example.android.apis.R" that could not be resolved... I imported the relevant XML file provided in the API and placed it into the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
...
 -->

<!-- This activity displays UI for launching voice recognition -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="......."
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        android:text="@string/voice_recognition_prompt" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_speak"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/speak_button" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And I added the voice_recognition_prompt and the speak_button strings to the value file (this is all new to me, i am not sure I have done these things in the right order).

Finally the app compiles but it just gives a force shut down error message. Is there any particular step that I may have missed? Some specific project configuration to use this Google API sample?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello Alex, Check My Answer if it is true then Mark is Right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Alex Please Use Following XML File:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="4dip"
        android:text="prompt" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_speak" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="speak" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

then check, your force close error is solved.

Comment: Your XML file did indeed fix the problem. Thank you very much. The app doesn't work properly on the emulator, says "Recogniser not present" but I had heard other people mentioning this.... But if deployed on a phone with Google Voice Search installed it does indeed work and print the words spoken.... Thanks again Dipak!!