# Implementing voice recognition in android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

i have used the code provided in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256079/cant-implement-google-api-sample-voicerecognition) for the speech recognition. in emulator it is saying recognizer not present,so i installed it on mobile. when i click on speak button it is working. but when i speak some names "rajesh" it is showing some possible verbs and all but not the name. but i want to use the input to select a contact from the address book in order to  make a call . so please tell me how to carry on in this direction. one more thing, every time i need to develop the code in eclipse then install it on mobile and then check for output. is there any alternative to edit and check the app code in the mobile from eclipse.
please provide me any possible links. i want to develop a call app for blind,if the voice recognition does not work, what else could be done to take input from the user.

Comment: the recognizer is not showing the words spoken in text box for many words. how can i sort out this problem.

Comment: I have seen in forums that recognizer takes the input,goes to google servers and return with results. is it possible for me store my voice for each character  in DB and when i speak letter by letter recognizer takes it and only searches in the DB for match.so letter by letter i can search for contact.can it be done?

Comment: If not in android ,is it possible to accomplish it in J2ME...

Comment: What do you mean by " to edit and check the app code in the mobile from eclipse"?

Answer (score 0):

Names are hard for Speech recognition. There are more possible names in the world than words in any dictionary, so being able to recognise ***any*** arbitrary name is hard. Though common names are easier.

Anyway, if you want to recognise a ***customized*** list of words/names, You might want to look at Dragon Mobile from Nuance. Here is a copy-and-paste from another similar question I answered:

If you use 3rd party Android recognition from Nuance (The people behind DragonDictate), it supports a "grammar mode" where you can somewhat restrict the phrases that will be recognised during recognition.

Importantly, if you add unusual names into a Custom Vocabulary, they SHOULD become recognizable (Complex pronunciation issues aside).

You can find information if you dig through:
http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com ,
looking for 'Custom Vocabularies'. Grammar mode is essentially a special mode of custom vocabularies.

At the time of writing, there was a document here that makes some mention of grammar mode: 
http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/downloads/custom_vocabulary/Guide_to_Custom_Vocabularies_v1.5.pdf - It only really becomes clear when you try to progress in their provisioning web GUI.

You have to set up an account, and jump through other hoops, but there is a free tier. This is the only potential way I have found to constrain a recognition vocabulary.
Well, short of running up PocketSphinx, but that is still described as a 'Research' 'PreAlpha'.

No, I don't work for Nuance. Not sure anyone does. They may have all been eaten by zombies. You would guess as much reading their support forums. They never reply.